# Archive page for Wordpress Custom Post Type doesn't show pagination from paginate_links()

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-post-type-archives, paginate-links

I have a custom post type with `courses-events` as the slug.

In functions.php, I have:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_archive_items' );
function custom_archive_items( $query ) {
  if ($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'courses-events')) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '1' );
  }
}
```

I know the above is firing for my archive page if I dump $query in the condition, it is visible.

On archive-courses-events.php I have simply:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
  while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    <!-- my output -->
  endwhile;
  
  echo paginate_links();
endif;
```

I have 2 posts and as `posts_per_page` is set to 1, but 2 posts appear and I do not see pagination.

I don't understand why this isn't working as everything I've read says that this is the minimum necessary for this to work?

Comment: Maybe there's a code (e.g. in a plugin) which is overriding your filter (or the `posts_per_page` setting), so you can try deactivating all plugins and see if the issue persists? Or try first with using a priority of 11 or greater, e.g. `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_archive_items', 20 );`

Comment: OH man, I feel a bit dumb but giving it a higher priority worked right away. Thank you. I completely overlooked that possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in a comment:

try first with using a priority of 11 or greater,
e.g.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_archive_items', 20 );
```